# Rails 5 app that works with bookings in several time zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 where users can book appointments in differente countries. Right now my database stores all dates in UTC and the Rails app is set to America/Sao_Paulo.

So if someone books an appointment for 14:00 the app will understand this to be Sao_Paulo and convert it to UTC. When I read the date to show it somewhere then Rails will automatically convert it back to Sao_Paulo. No hassle at all.

But now if someone books an appointment in Germany, I guess I have to take the input and parse it to Germany/Berlin. Rails will store it as UTC and I will have to create an extra column to store the time zone and when I want to display the time somewhere I have to manually convert it back to Berlin.

Am I getting this correct? I find this whole topic quite confusing.
Is there a Gem that handles all this for me?

Comment: When you say someone books an appointment in Germany, do you mean the person is in Germany or the appointment is in Germany? Could the person and the appointment be in different time zones? I assume you'd want to show the time in the time zone of the appointment's place, rather than the person's local time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any gem for this requirement.

I have handled this manually in my project. I gave an option of choosing Time Zone to user while selecting time.
In the backend, while saving you can convert time in UTC.

The best you can do for user is that write JS Code that sets the default value of TimeZone after the document loads using the TimeZone of user's system.

You can check the sample of this on my site [Shuriken Live](https://shurikenlive.com). Just sign-up and go to Live Polling Plugin and select any template. There try to schedule that post. I have used the same method there on my site.

Comment: The user actually selects a country, so I know in which time zone to convert.

Comment: I didn't find any gem when I tried to search around 1-2 months ago. So I ended up writing code myself. I also find managing Time related fields very irritating.

Comment: Thanks for the info...so you created a new column with the timezone and convert the time manually when parsing or reading?

Comment: Actually there is no need for me as of now to show absolute Time in user's TimeZone after submission of form. So I didn't store the TimeZone in Table. But, yes I parsed time fields manually and converted time to UTC to maintain uniformity.